# Where do i find my Google Wallet Transaction ID

Tags: google-play, android-pay

I am looking into transferring my app to another google account, but i can't find my "Transaction ID" as described here:

- [Transfer your
  application](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/checklist/3294213)

Any idea what i am missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As all answers seems **out-dated,** you can have a look at [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53933896/2289835)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The transaction ID is at the bottom of the receipt (specifically the receipt for the Developer Account when you first signed up) in your wallet dashboard payment history.

[image: Example]

Comment: Thanks, mine was formatted like:
0.G.123456789012345
And not like:
01234567890123456789.token.0123456789012345
as the instructions say - i suspect it's just because it's old. I got a reply from google confirming your answer.

Comment: +1 That should really be stated in the documentation like this. It only says it would be "available from the Google Wallet dashboard", no hint to the $25 sign-up receipt.

Comment: It should. It took me an exceptionally long time to find it, which is why I went to the trouble of answering this question.

Comment: well, now it disappeared :(

Comment: I got it : instead of looking in the Google wallet merchant center, just look in your personnal wallet console, and get the detail of the transaction you did when purchasing your Play Store registration : the transaction ID is print here. For newest developpers, this transaction ID is also sent to you in the mail you received after the payement.

Comment: this is very outdated

Answer (score 0):

Visit: https://payments.google.com

Once you are logged into your account, just press the "Subscriptions and services" menu button on the left. Then on the right-hand side, go through your completed purchases, going to the last page, depending on the amount of transactions.

Once you see [day-month-year Google Play $25.000] click on it.

A new menu on the right will show up. You will see the Transaction ID there.

Comment: For older applications the label might also simply say "Android".