# Transaction ID for google play to transfer app to another account

Tags: android, google-play

I need to transfer an app to another account. I already transferred many apps. But Google might have changed the way to get *TRANSACTION-ID.*

I've already visited below answers: and all seems **OUT-DATED.**

- [Find transaction ID on Google Play to transfer apps in 2017.](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwifu8Wh3b3fAhXGsI8KHU_CDSsQFjAAegQICBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F45166672%2Ffind-transaction-id-on-google-play-to-transfer-apps-in-2017&usg=AOvVaw0Ejkh_urFhEsG_Bjp0YQn4)
- [Google pay not showing transaction I'd after paying google play console registration fee under subscription and services.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53750136/google-pay-not-showing-transaction-id-after-paying-google-play-console-registra)
- [Android App Transfer Can't Find Transaction Id.](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwifu8Wh3b3fAhXGsI8KHU_CDSsQrAIoATAAegQICBAJ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F51940519%2Fandroid-app-transfer-cant-find-transaction-id&usg=AOvVaw31auGIQOPtPUH9qqo7EPlt)
- [Where do I find my Google Wallet Transaction ID.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18711515/where-do-i-find-my-google-wallet-transaction-id)

They all are suggested to go-to Payment Page. I tried all the URLs listed below.

- https://payments.google.com/
- https://payments.google.com/payments/u/0/home#subscriptionsAndServices
- https://payments.google.com/payments/u/0/home#oneTimePurchase

But they all are redirecting on the same [**very same Url !!**](https://pay.google.com/payments/u/0/home#subscriptionsAndServices) and displaying page below:

[image]

So is there any Url which reaches the correct page which can provide *TRANSACTION-ID.*

Answer (score 51):

If your order id is "01234567890123456789.token.0123456789012345"
Just remove the part before “token”

If your order id is "0123456789.Registration.0123456789", just remove the part before "Registration"

Comment: Finally it worked!! This must be the accepted answer!

Comment: I can't believe they don't make this clearer anywhere I can see. Thanks for the help!

Comment: And if it’s “0.G.012345678901234”, remove the leading “0.G.”.

Comment: wtf... thanks bud.... why google don't update their documentation

Comment: It's 2023 and I have to find out that I need to remove a portion of an entire string that was given that was also requested for a form submission from a platform independent of Google

Comment: It's 2024, and this is still incorrect on the Google help text and linked docs for transferring an app (https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6230247#zippy=%2Cstep-find-the-target-account-transaction-id). I submitted feedback on that docs page with the details of this problem---hopefully they will update.

Answer (score 5):

---

### **UPDATE (2nd Nov. 2022):**

---

**Solution 1:** Search ***developer registration fee*** or ***payments-noreply@google.com*** keyword in inbox. If an email like below is found, we can get the transaction id directly from the email.

[image]

---

**Solution 2:** Get transaction id from https://pay.google.com

[image: transaction id error by play-store]

---

**Solution 3:**

If your order id is **01234567890123456789.token.0123456789012345** Just remove the part before **token**

If your order id is **0123456789.Registration.0123456789**, just remove the part before **Registration**

---

**Solution 4:**

This is **not recommended** way but, append **PDS.** before **Payments profile ID / Transaction ID.**

For example my Id was **4766-8303-0058** and now Id is **PDS.4766-8303-0058** you can use.

In my case, It worked like charm !!!

---

Get more info from [Transfer apps to a different developer account](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6230247) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51836336/2289835).

Comment: how many days did it took you between creating a new play account and trnasferring it? I am still getting: The transaction ID does not match for this developer account even though i put PDS.x.x.....

Comment: @WantIt , I think 12-24 hours. not more then a day.

Comment: @WantIt Have a look at this thread - seems they have problem with the form: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/play/SVV7SAWs68s/VDHvlnE5DAAJ

Comment: Thanks for answer. I was fighting with this issue for several days. I'll check it ASAP.

Comment: I have this exact issue now, and I do append **PDS.** but still get "The transaction ID does not match for this developer account", so I am lost.

Comment: @mattsson can't you access you payment -id from [this URL?](https://payments.google.com/)

Comment: The error was caused by entering the wrong target account email address

Comment: Solution 3 - works for me!!!

Answer (score 3):

As it stands currently (8-1-2019), the new form (which directs you to your playstore console) to transfer apps to different accounts found here is **NOT** working:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6230247?hl=en

I know this because I used to be able to transfer my apps no problem with the old form. But using the new form, I always get the error "**the transaction ID does not match for this developer account**" in the target ID field. I have already emailed google seeking support, will update if I get a response.

Comment: Have you got any response? Whom did you ask? I have the same issue now and cannot find any option to contact a human out there :(

Comment: nope no response, they really need to test their stuff before making it public. I am surprised not many people complain about it either... Basically old form was working fine, but they had to make a new one that fails. A typical case of if it ain't broken, don't fix it

Comment: I still have this issue now, February 2020.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem - neither we nor our client were able to find the transaction ID. By contacting the support team, I was sent in circles for quite some time (from Google Play to Google Pay support and so on). In the end I was sent the the [Play Console support team](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/gethelp).

Finally a human (Laura!) responded and after pointing me once again to the "How to find your Transaction ID" standard posting I asked her if there is any other possibility to show Google that we are the right company and everyhting that is needed to initiate a transfer. She agreed. We had to send her as much as possible from this list

- Primary email address associated with the developer account
- Developer Account ID
- Merchant Account ID
- *Date of Play Console account registration
- Website
- Physical Address
- Mailing address and phone number registered for your Play Console Developer account
- *Last 4 digits of the active credit card used to purchase the registration fee

We could provide all but the bullet points with the *.

I sent all the information on Friday and on Monday I got the OK from Google for the transfer. They initiated it already, the client accepted the transfer and now it is pending. A tour de force that started in May 2022 ended now.